# Removing No Data From Raster (*.sid) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, imagery

I have an Image.sid that has a white border which is No Data.
I've tried using Clip Raster Tool with no success.
I've also changed the symbology value for No Data to be transparent.

I'd like to remove No Data if possible or simply trim / erase the white border.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there are some issues involving compression in SID files, have you seen some of the possible solutions on the ESRI forum?

[Possible 1](http://geonet.esri.com/message/24758) -- Set the likely NoData color vector (0,0,0) to transparent.

[Possible 2](https://geonet.esri.com/message/98116) -- Multiple possibilities, focusing on converting to a format over which you have more control.

Comment: +1 Note that the second set of solutions destroys any advantages of the extreme compression afforded by the MRSID format and might not be practicable for large images (they can expand to hundreds of gigabytes and counting...).

Answer (score 2):

I don't wish to sound arrogant, but try a different raster format.  I've had issues with mrsid images in the past and still find their quality after compression less than ideal (for high-res images anyway)

JPEG2000 is a great one to start with, it'll maintain no-data fields after compression, maintains good resolution on conversion and has a small foot print on storage.  I seldom find artifacts in JPG2000 images created from the compression process.

Not a solution, just offering another option.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of the raster using the Copy Raster Data tool (Data Management) and it has an option for setting the No Data to zero.

Comment: Interesting!  Do you know for sure whether this works for MRSID files?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to LizardTech's GeoExpress software, it can do this. If you need to do it in ArcGIS, you might try converting it to an uncompressed form and doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One option I have used is by

1. generating a mosaic dataset
2. using the build footprints tool (radiometry, make sure update boundary is checked)
   if, during the Build Footprints phase, the boundary polygon created is not following the boundary of your imagery sufficiently, you can edit the polygon to fit more closely, or create an entirely new polygon ( you likely have one from trying to clip your imagery) and use the import mosaic dataset geometry tool
3. Using the set mosaic dataset properties tool and clipping the mosaic to the 'boundary'.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this process, outlined in the resource centre?  I think it is what you are trying to do:

ESRI ArcGIS 10 Resource centre

[Removing a color representing NoData from an image service definition](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009s00000076000000.htm)

Comment: It seems this is for an "image server" rather than ArcGIS itself.  Would the procedure actually apply to ArcGIS?  Do you know whether it works for MRSID format?

Comment: Ahhh, that's very mature...

Comment: If you're referring to the downvote, that is because the reply, as it stands, appears off-target and a month-old request for clarification remains unanswered.

Comment: Of course Whuber.  Just like .PointPosition is only one line of code...